# Advertencia Nª CA2100 al ejecutar análisis de Código

Tags: c#

Realizando un análisis al código de mi proyecto me encuentro con la siguiente advertencia

> Advertencia   1678    CA2100 : Microsoft.Security : La cadena de consulta
>   pasada a 'SqlCommand.SqlCommand(string, SqlConnection)' en
>   'Data_Metodos_Cierre.Actualizar_Fecha_Obreros_Produccion_Transaction(DateTime,
>   DateTime)' podría contener las siguientes variables:
>   'FechaIni.ToShortDateString()'. Si alguna de estas variables puede
>   proceder de datos proporcionados por el usuario, considere el uso de
>   un procedimiento almacenado o una consulta SQL parametrizada en lugar
>   de compilar la consulta con concatenaciones de cadenas.

El código que adjunto a continuación es el que indica la advertencia.

```
 public void Actualizar_Fecha_Obreros_Produccion_Transaction(DateTime FechaIni,DateTime FechaFin)
    {
        string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlTransaction transaction;
            //Inicia la Transaccion Local.
            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("InicioTransacción");
            try
            {
                SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [TBL_MOV_PROD] SET [Mov_Fechai] = '" + FechaIni.ToShortDateString() + "'", connection); --> AQUI INDICA LA ADVERTENCIA
                SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [TBL_MOV_PROD] SET [Mov_Fechaf] = '" + FechaFin.ToShortDateString() + "'", connection); --> AQUI INDICA LA ADVERTENCIA

                // Must assign both transaction object and connection 
                // to Command object for a pending local transaction
                command1.Connection = connection;
                command1.Transaction = transaction;
                command2.Connection = connection;
                command2.Transaction = transaction;                 

                command1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;                    

                command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                command2.ExecuteNonQuery();                    

                // Attempt to commit the transaction.
                transaction.Commit();
                //MessageBox.Show("Proceso de Cierre Terminado Satisfactoriamente", "SISROL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Excepción Tipo Commit " + ex.GetType() + " El Mensaje de Excepción: " + ex.Message, "SISROL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                // Attempt to roll back the transaction. 
                try
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }
                catch (Exception ex2)
                {
                    // This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred 
                    // on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as 
                    // a closed connection.
                    MessageBox.Show("Excepción Tipo Rollback " + ex2.GetType() + " El Mensaje de Excepción: " + ex2.Message, "SISROL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

A simple vista no le veo nada erróneo , pero recurro al foro para que me puedan indicar el motivo de esta advertencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomando en cuenta la respuesta realizada por **Guasy** , adapte ese código y realice unas modificaciones para que no arroje ningún tipo de advertencia posterior, adjunto como quedaría el código finalmente.

```
public void Actualizar_Fecha_Obreros_Produccion_Transaction(DateTime FechaIni,DateTime FechaFin)
    {
        string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();
        SqlCommand command1=null;
        SqlCommand command2=null;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlTransaction transaction;
            //Inicia la Transaccion Local.
            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("InicioTransacción");
            try
            {
                String FecIni = FechaIni.ToShortDateString();
                String FecFin = FechaFin.ToShortDateString();
                command1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [TBL_MOV_PROD] SET [Mov_Fechai] = @Mov_Fechai", connection);
                command1.Parameters.Add("@Mov_Fechai", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = FecIni;
                command2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [TBL_MOV_PROD] SET [Mov_Fechaf] = @Mov_Fechaf", connection);
                command2.Parameters.Add("@Mov_Fechaf", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = FecFin;
                // Must assign both transaction object and connection 
                // to Command object for a pending local transaction
                command1.Connection = connection;
                command1.Transaction = transaction;
                command2.Connection = connection;
                command2.Transaction = transaction;

                command1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                command2.ExecuteNonQuery();                   

                // Attempt to commit the transaction.
                transaction.Commit();
                //MessageBox.Show("Proceso de Cierre Terminado Satisfactoriamente", "SISROL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Excepción Tipo Commit " + ex.GetType() + " El Mensaje de Excepción: " + ex.Message, "SISROL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                // Attempt to roll back the transaction. 
                try
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }
                catch (Exception ex2)
                {
                    // This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred 
                    // on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as 
                    // a closed connection.
                    MessageBox.Show("Excepción Tipo Rollback " + ex2.GetType() + " El Mensaje de Excepción: " + ex2.Message, "SISROL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (command1 != null)
                {
                    ((IDisposable)command1).Dispose();
                }
                if (command2 != null)
                {
                    ((IDisposable)command2).Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

No puedes ni debes de concatenar en tu consulta alguna variable que la cambies a `string`, es decir con el .`ToString()` ya que es una vulnerabilidad. Puedes crear una variable donde guardes tu fecha en `string` y luego concatenarla.

Lo recomendable es ocupar parametros de SQL o generar un `Stored Procedure`

Te adjunto un ejemplo de como generar consultas con parametros

```
           da.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE complain SET Name = @NAME,Email = @EMAIL,Message= @MESSAGE", con);
           da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@NAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = nameTextBox.Text;
           da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@EMAIL", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = emailTextBox.Text;
           da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@MESSAGE", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = messageTextBox.Text;

           con.Open();
           da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
           con.Close();
```

Fuente del ejemplo:
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/251671/SQL-Database-Update-using-Csharp